# Why do the mounting screws for my new device not fit the threads in the box?

Tags: electrical

The screws supplied with my new Leviton outlets do not fit into 55 yr. old outlet boxes.  I have to use old outlet screws to attach new outlets otherwise the new screws get stripped.

Why?

Comment: Pictures of the screws and your box may help. I have some 100 year old outlet boxes in my house, and they use the same threads as the current equipment today.

Answer (score 1):

The asked question:

> Why?

Pure conjecture, but a likely scenarios:

- At some point during the 55 years the box has been in the wall someone stripped the original screw holes. To fix the issue, someone tapped the holes with a different thread and put different screws in.
- Since this seems to be an across the board issue with multiple boxes, at some point, somebody used a handful of screws with the wrong threads and either forced them in or retapped multiple boxes to match the screws on hand instead of buying new screws with the proper threads.

---

The unasked question:

> How do I fix it?

You either:

- Live with it and don't lose the existing screws.
- Retap the holes to the standard fixture mounting thread.

  - I don't know what it is off-hand, but if you have a tap & die set, you'll be able to use the thread gauge that should come with it to ID the thread.
  - It's possible that you won't be able to do this (not enough metal left for a 3rd set of threads), so you'd have to drill out the holes to be larger then tap the fresh metal. Oh, wait, then the screw will be too big to fit the hole in the device you're mounting.
- Pull it out of the wall and replace it with a new box that is tapped to the standard device mounting screw.

Comment: Old boxes and outlets are original, shown by the original paint over the ears and screws of the outlets, not retapped.  I tried the new screws in a newer box and found that if they are not aligned perfectly then only the end of the screw will go in and the rest will strip.  I guess that the new screws do not tolerate even the slightest misalignment (not like the old screws), which is difficult to achieve in some retrofit situations. Thank you.